# How to automatically input zip passwords in unzip command in bash script

Tags: shell-script, zip

I want to test 10 passwords against a zip file. If i type:

`unzip file.zip`

the output is:

```
Archive:  file.zip
[file.txt] file.txt password:
```

I want to create a bash script that test 10 passwords. How can I input these 10 passwords to this line:

```
[file.txt] file.txt password:
```

using bash script?

Comment: `unzip -P password1 file.zip`?

Comment: no the bash script stops if the password is wrong. It wont go to try next line.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Put your 10 guesses in a file called password.list.
Then iterate through that file and try each guess one at a time. 
Like so:

```
#!/bin/sh
for i in $(cat password.list)
do
  unzip -P "$i" file.zip && exit 0 || echo "sorry, did not find password"
done
```

This will exit upon guessing correctly but otherwise it will continue to the end of file.